# Is there an XSD or similar declaration for Facebook's API method signatures?

Tags: facebook, schema

I'm developing a generator to create a C# API wrapper for Facebook's API. I'm just about finished with the basic coding, except that there doesn't seem to be any well-formed declaration of the method signatures of all the API methods.

I can parse the [schema for the element types](http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd) to figure out what the names of all the methods are (they're anything at the end that ends with `_response` - they all have a corresponding method). The signatures are [documented on their wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API), but there doesn't seem to be a single place they're all defined, as in a schema.

Any suggestions, besides screen scraping the wiki?

---

One step closer: All the signatures seem to be defined in JSON on the [API Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?api) page. Of course, this doesn't help with typing, but having it all in once place makes it a bit less work if I'm going to screen scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook never released such a document, and the REST API that this question relates to has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Facebook XSD at http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd. It defines the full schema and has the information you are looking for neatly packaged. No need to screen scrape :-p

Comment: Yup, and I linked to that in my question, saying "The signatures are documented on their wiki, but there doesn't seem to be a single place they're all defined, as in a schema." The XSD does not have the signatures of the methods defined, only the types that are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the C# SDK for the Graph API.  It might not have the type safety you're looking for, but it is fairly complete and can be used with a variety of .net app types (MVC, WinForms, ASP.NET, etc)

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/